# Sample JavaScript can't connect to Ruby WebSocket server

Tags: javascript, ruby, sockets, websocket, handshake

I would like to fiddle with websockets a bit. I installed a Ruby gem called "websocket-ruby" (https://github.com/imanel/websocket-ruby) I started a pry / IRB session and typed:

```
require "websocket"
@handshake = WebSocket::Handshake::Server.new(:host => "localhost", :port => 8080,:secure=>true)
```

This starts a websocket server as far as I know. Then I opened in my browser the Javascript HTML page which attempt to connect to the server:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Websocket Client</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080");
    exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
      exampleSocket.send("Can you hear me?"); 
    };
    exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it says in the console log:

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I tried different ports both in server and in the client respectively: 8081, 12345, but I always get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea about websocket and javascript, but not websocket-ruby.
I hope it will helpful you.

In nodejs.. server.js file, write below code

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port:8100});

console.log("websocket Server is Running...");

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    // Store the remote systems IP address as "remoteIp".
    var remoteIp = ws.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress;
    // Print a log with the IP of the client that connected.
    console.log('Connection received: ', remoteIp);
    // Add a listener which listens for the "message" event.

    // When a "message" event is received, take the contents
    // of the message and pass it to the broadcast() function.
    ws.on('message', wss.broadcast);
});

wss.broadcast = function(msg) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        client.send(msg);
    })
};
```

In javascript...

```
 var SERVER_URL = 'ws://localhost:8100'; 
         //instead of localhost you can also use IP address of your system
 var ws;

    function connect() {
      alert('connect');
        ws = new WebSocket(SERVER_URL, []);
        // Set the function to be called when a message is received.
        ws.onmessage = handleMessageReceived;
        // Set the function to be called when we have connected to the server.
        ws.onopen = handleConnected;
        // Set the function to be called when an error occurs.
        ws.onerror = handleError;
    }

    function handleMessageReceived(data) {
        // Simply call logMessage(), passing the received data.
        logMessage(data.data);
    }

    function handleConnected(data) {
        // Create a log message which explains what has happened and includes
        // the url we have connected too.
        var logMsg = 'Connected to server: ' + data.target.url;
        // Add the message to the log.
        logMessage(logMsg)
    }

    function handleError(err) {
        // Print the error to the console so we can debug it.
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    }

    function logMessage(msg) {
        // with the new message.
       console.log(msg);
    }

    /** This is the scope function that is called when a users hits send. */
    function sendMessage{
        ws.send(msg); 
    };
connect();
```

in html use one button to send message to websocket server

```
<button onclick="sendMessage('Hi Websocket')">send message</button>
```

Comment: Thx, but what is $scope? Console says "$scope is not defined". Is it JQuery?

Comment: I have edited now... plz check once. if you get any doubt, feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the Ruby code you presented does **not** start a Websocket *server*... what it does is initiate a server-side **parser**.

To start a server you need to use an actual websocket server.

ActionCable (with Rails) uses the `websocket-ruby` library to parse websocket events and it uses `nio4r` to operate the actual server.

[Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby) have a similar solution and [`em-websockets`](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-eventmachine-server) use the `websocket-ruby` gem with EventMachine.

Other Ruby Websocket servers include [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine), which uses the C library [`facil.io`](http://facil.io). Iodine is used by the framework [plezi](http://plezi.io) as well as independently.

Since you were trying to run an echo server, here's a quick example using the Plezi framework (you can use it as middleware in Sinatra or Rails)...

...place the following in a `config.ru` file:

```
require 'plezi'
class WebsocketSample
  # HTTP index
  def index
    'Hello World!'
  end

  # called when Websocket data is recieved
  #
  # data is a string that contains binary or UTF8 (message dependent) data.
  def on_message(data)
    puts "Websocket got: #{data}"
    write data
  end
end
Plezi.route '/', WebsocketSample
run Plezi.app
```

To run the server, call (ignore the `$` sign, it marks this code as terminal code):

```
$ iodine
```

**notice**: Iodine requires a BSD / Unix / Linux machine, such as macOS, Ubuntu, etc'. It won't work on windows.